# How to trigger a tag only sometimes?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Like, a percentage of the times.

The first thing that comes to mind is doing something like

```js
if (0.10 < Math.random()) { /* send event */ }
```

But What I'm asking, is, is there a more elegant way of doing so? like a configuration that I couldn't find on the dashboard, or something the API presents for doing so?

Comment: Basically that is the way, although if you do this from within GTM you probably would use an existing event and set a custom javascript variable to "true" for some percent of the visitors (else you'd need a custom html tag to fire that event, and that is uncessary overhead).

Comment: ok thanks, I was just fishing for a more proper way of doing that, if that way did exists, thanks for the help :D